# SQL statement using contains invalid

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to get a SQL query to return messages that contain an inputted string. The query works without that WHERE CONTAINS part of the SQL statement, but either returns nothing or returns a SQL invalid error when trying to get the WHERE CONTAINS part to work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
 "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages WHERE text CONTAINS ? ORDER BY posted_at DESC;"
```

Other syntax I've tried:

```
"SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages WHERE CONTAINS(text, ?) ORDER BY posted_at DESC;"

"SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC;"
```

Comment: Is `CONTAINS` a MySQL operator?  I don't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last should work if you phrase it as:

```
SELECT user_username, text, posted_at
FROM Messages
WHERE text LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
ORDER BY posted_at DESC
```

Comment: Ah great that worked! Been stuck on this for too long, thank you!